# ECM Application using Alfresco

Tags: project, alfresco

I am new to Alfresco Development. I had learn Alfresco Implementation and Usage little bit. Now i want to develop a application using Alfresco, ie, Knowledge Management Application with customized UI with my defined features only. No need to be with full features of Alfresco. **Where should i start?** I heard that there is two ways to develop Alfresco project, by Customizing Alfresco Explorer for my own need, or Create a new application on extending Alfresco features by API.I could't be clear for developing ECM Project using Alfresco.Can anyone pls guide me to do my wish? I am in end of days for my project.
Thank in advance,
with regards,
Feroz

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you first spend some time learning about how to create a simple content model and how to modify the UI to display your stuff.  One good tutorial can be found on [www.ecmarchitect.com](http://www.ecmarchitect.com), look for custom content model example.